# I have a php file which gives JSON output and want to use that JSON in D3

Tags: javascript, php, json, d3.js

I have a php file names **test.php** which gives me a JSON output which is a valid output as I have validated in http://jsonlint.com/ .I want to use that JSON directly in my .html code which used D3.

**test.php**

```
<?php
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "scheduler";

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $password, $database) or die ("Unable to connect"); 

    $query = "SELECT semone.userid AS id,  semone.semester AS semester, semone.cname AS name, courses.credit AS value, courses.progskill AS skill
    FROM semone
    INNER JOIN courses
    ON semone.cname = courses.coname" ;

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die ("Unable to connect");

    $lastId = null;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $row['xyz'] = array(
                        'name'=> $row['name'],
                        'value'=> $row['value']    
                       );

        $info[$row['semester']]['semester'] = $row['semester'];
        $info[$row['semester']]['children'][]= $row['xyz'];

        $lastId = $row['id'];
    }

    // do not call json_encode on each iteration of the loop
    $data = json_encode(array('id' => $row['id'], 'children' => array_values($info)));
    // echo $data;
?>
```

The html code where I am trying to use the JSON created from test.php in D3.

**tree.html**

```
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width",width)
        .attr("height",height + padding);

var data;

d3.json("test3.php", function (error,json) {

    if(error) return console.warn(error);
    data = json;
    console.log(data);

    var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
        .size([550,550])
        .nodes(data);

    var cells = canvas.selectAll(".cell")
        .data(treemap)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class","cell")
```

It is not showing anything as if it is not able to access that JSON file. However When I am using the same JSON through some JSON file saved in the folder, it is working fine. So there is some problem in connection of this html and php file.

Comment: Strange server code. You got $data output commented and $row['id'] exists only in while loop. You are trying to use it in json_encode outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment the **echo $data** . It should work fine.

Comment: I am sorry for such a lame error. I just forgot to uncomment it and was looking for error all around.